# Histogram and text file

Tags: java

[code in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGBEh.png)

```java
public class readtxtfile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Write a program that creates a histogram that allows you to visually inspect the frequency distribution of a set of values. The program should read in an arbitrary number of integers from a text input file called data.txt that are in the range of 1 to 100 inclusive; then produce a chart similar to the one below that indicates how many input values fell into the range. 1-10, 11-20, and so on. Print one asterisk for each value entered.

1 -  10: *****
11 - 20: *****************
21 - 30: ***
31 - 40: *******
41 - 50: **
51 - 60: *************

// complete the chart until you reach
91 - 100: *******

Comment: Don't post a picture of your code - post the code. And the code should actually try to solve the problem - not just some file reading boilerplate!

Comment: If anyone tries to help you, they have to either run the code in their head, or type the code from your image.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```java
public class readtxtfile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] histogram = new int[10];
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
                int inRange = (num-1)/10;
                histogram[inRange] = histogram[inRange] + 1;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                System.out.print("\n"+((i*10)+1)+" - "+((i+1)*10)+" : ");
                for(int j=0;j<histogram[i];j++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1
5
33
45
43
1
21
11
10
12
65
78
65
```

Output:

```
1 - 10 : ****
11 - 20 : **
21 - 30 : *
31 - 40 : *
41 - 50 : **
51 - 60 : 
61 - 70 : **
71 - 80 : *
81 - 90 : 
91 - 100 :
```

Comment: Yes, It would have been simpler with `inRange = (num-1)/10; ++histogram[inRange]`.

Comment: Yes @MauricePerry you right I updated ans as you suggested

Comment: Oh! and I see two numbers between 11 and 20; how do you get to five?

Comment: It s 2 only was typo mistake